# Compairing two strings [words]

Tags: python, string

I am trying to build a statistical model. In between I am stuck at the following situation:

```
for pos_token in tokens:
    for pos_feature_word in pos_features:
```

here, **tokens** are the tokens of the incoming sentence and **pos_features** is a .txt file.

Here **pos_token** and **pos_feature_word** are the word(string). How can I match them?

Like: My objective is to get something like this:

```
if pos_token == pos_feature_word
```

**Info:** I am trying to match the complete string(word) and not the characters in string. So order of characters is important. what I am doing is (for now), creating a set of pos_token if they exist in the list of pos_features that I have created.

Comment: Doesn't "if pos_token == pos_feature_word" work?

Comment: no, It's not working.

Comment: Can you give an example where it's not working? What are `pos_token` and `pos_feature_word` in that case, what's the result and what you're expecting the result to be?

Comment: what I am doing is (for now), creating a set of pos_token if they exist in the list of pos_features that I have created.

Comment: are you looking for `if pos_token in pos_features:` ?

Comment: If `pos_token` and `pos_feature_word` are stings, like "cat" and "dog", `pos_token == pos_feature_word` should return `True` when they are the same words. Either that's a poorly phased question or, you are doing doing something very wrong and not mentioning it

Comment: @ParitoshSingh I tried, its not working that way too.

Comment: @Ayxan man I wrote everything I am doing. Do not mislead. I guess this negative is also your thing. Doesn't make sense

Comment: @Ayxan Don't make degrading remarks and add negativity, else you will be reported to the moderator. It goes against the spirit of sharing on SO.

Comment: @cph_sto Am I being negative? I just made a comment saying this question is not clear; Most of the comments are trying to figure out what is being asked, and one of the answers did something the question is not asking for. Adding just one example input and the expected output would have fixed all of that, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not enough clear to find what is you problem but maybe you have a problem with the reading from the file. I have created a similar script which works well, try it and find what was bad in yours.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

tokens = ["cat", "dog", "fish"]
filename = "pos_features.txt"

with open(filename, "r") as pos_features:
    for pos_feature_word in pos_features.readlines():
        for pos_token in tokens:
            if pos_token == pos_feature_word.strip():
                print ("equal at", pos_token)
```

The content of the **pos_features.txt**:

```
cat
bird
turtle
dog
```

The output will be:

```
equal at cat
equal at dog
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone doing a statistical model you're having a very bad time explaining your problem.

From my understanding you want to check if both strings have the same characters, rather than being equal. If that is it, first check the length of both strings, they must be equal if they are going to have the same characters, the loop through the characters in one string and check if the exist in the other.

```
def have_same_chars(a, b):
    if (len(a) != len(b)):
        return False

    for a_char in a:
        if a_char not in b:
            return False

    return True
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but how this will keep track of the order of words. for example: str1 = "must" and str2 = "umst" then your function will return true. which is not what I want as order of character is important to me.

Comment: Well, I've said to you, you're having a bad time explaining your problem. My understanding was as you saw, if it is not what you meant then rephrase your problem. If your interested in the order just do a normal == comparison, whats the issue with that?